# Java console log how to hide method execution

Tags: java, windows, maven, logging

I'm running a .jar file and when I do run it, I'm seeing my methods being executed...

```
INFO: ------- Order #295389
Mar 11, 2013 2:10:31 PM com.production.tasks.ImportNewOrders checkForOrders
INFO:     - Order has already been imported
Mar 11, 2013 2:10:31 PM com.production.tasks.ImportNewOrders checkForOrders
INFO: ...finished fetching orders, will check again in 60 seconds
```

I would much rather just see...

```
INFO: ------- Order #295389
INFO:     - Order has already been imported
INFO: ...finished fetching orders, will check again in 60 seconds
```

How can I block method execution from the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't log4j doing this, but it was actually `java.util.logging` logging each method call.

This will hide the method calls:

`System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "%4$s: %5$s%n");`

Answer (score 1):

You have to change Log level to log only higher level logs. It's `INFO` right now(guessed from your output in question) you can set it `WARN` that will only log messages that are warning or of higher level. You can find those setting in configuration file. For more information about different levels go through this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_quick_guide.htm) for log4j.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Log4J, find your log4j.properties file.  Note the ConversionPattern properties used.  In particular, I think you need to remove `C` (fully-qualified class name) and `M` (method name).  See [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) for a complete list of options.

Answer (score 0):

That is not standard java output. It looks like you have a logging framework logging that out (likely log4j, slf4j, logback, java logger, or commons logging). You would have to configure your logging to not print out the method information.

Comment: I tried adding `System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");` to my main() and it didn't make it disappear.  Though, I'm also not actively using apache log commons - I'm using `java.util.logging.Logger` - I do have apache commons included and am using it for other reasons.

Comment: If you're using java logger then setting the commons property won't do anything. What do your log handlers look like (what pattern are they set to display)?